# Why can't I instantiate and create Object without main method? (Stack Overflow Error)

Tags: java

**My Code:**

(causes a Stack Overflow Error)

```
public class Overloads {
    String uniqueID;    
    Overloads ov2=new Overloads();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("IN MAIN");
    }

    public void setUniqueID(String theID) {
        // II lots of validation code, and then:
        uniqueID = theID;
        System.out.println(uniqueID);
    }
}
```

**This Code Works Fine:**

```
public class Overloads {
    String uniqueID;   

    public static void main(String[] args) {
          Overloads ov2=new Overloads();
          System.out.println("IN MAIN");
    }

    public void setUniqueID(String theID) {
        // II lots of validation code, and then:
        uniqueID = theID;
        System.out.println(uniqueID);           
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem with your first code is that creating an instance of `Overloads` involves creating another instance of `Overloads` thanks to having this field: `Overloads ov2=new Overloads();`.

Answer (score 12):

The presence of main method is not relevant here. The scope in which you have declared the variables, however, is very important.

Have you walked through what happens in the first version of the code?

```
Create new instance of Overloads
  -> ov2 = Create new instance of Overloads
      -> ov2 = Create new instance of Overloads
         -> ov2 = Create new instance of Overloads
```

and so on. The variable `ov2` is in scope of the class, thus it is initialized whenever an instance of the class is instantiated. This will never terminate until you run out of memory and get the stack overflow. Run it with a debugger for a clearer view.

The second version of the code only instantiates one instace of `Overloads`, in the scope of the main method. Thus creating one instance does not lead to the newly created instance creating new instance and so on..

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this

```
public class Overloads {
    String uniqueID;
    static Overloads ov2 = new Overloads();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("IN MAIN");
    }

    public void setUniqueID(String theID) {
        // II lots of validation code, and then:
        uniqueID = theID;
        System.out.println(uniqueID);
    }
}
```

this will create shared instance of Overloads, instantiation will be done only once, when class loaded